# Xamarin Android Callback not calling ShouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, redirect, xamarin, webview, callback

I just need to know whether this is possible. I am trying to handle a redirect callback of the form when using a Xamarin Android `WebView` and a `WebViewClient`.

```
io.identitymodel.native://callback
```

I am basically trying to implement the OpenId connect handshake using a WebView rather than a external browser. The reason for this is we do no want to show a logon page at all (don't ask!).

Unfortunately I cannot handle it before it gets loaded e.g. OnPageLoaded is called and ShouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called for the callback Url. What I want to happen is that I can handle this somewhere before it is loaded and start an Activity with an intent.

It seems there was a change in KitKat which seemed to stopped ShouldOverrideUrlLoading getting called for a callback which was not a valid Url. [Url migration with WebViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating#URLs)

Has anyone managed to do this with a webView for KitKat and beyond.

Any proven solutions welcomed.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979950/webviewclient-not-calling-shouldoverrideurlloading).

Comment: Yes, I ad seen this, but none of it seems to work.